# How egregious is it to "borrow" the request object to store temporary data in node.js?

Tags: node.js

Given code like this from a node.js neophyte like me:

```
require('http').createServer(function( req, resp ) {
    var pathname = require('url').parse( req.url ).pathname;

    if( req.method === "POST" ) {
        var postData = "";
        req.addListener( "data", function( postDataChunk ) {
            postData += postDataChunk;
        });
        req.addListener( "end", function() {
            // do my thing with postData
            // and end the response
        });
    }
}).listen(8888);
```

...every time there's a `POST` request, the set of anonymous functions sent to the listeners are recreated.

This seems (almost) required since node doesn't send a second *accumulator* argument to the `"data"` listener, or a final result argument to the `"end"` listener. As such, the anonymous functions need to reference the `postData` variable in order to build the result.

My preference is to have named functions for the listeners created *outside* the server request handler, like this:

```
function data_listener( postDataChunk ) {
    this.some_unique_property.accumulator += postDataChunk;
}
function end_listener() {
    // do my thing with postData
    // and end the response
}

require('http').createServer(function( req, resp ) {
    var pathname = require('url').parse( req.url ).pathname;

    if( req.method === "POST" ) {
        req.some_unique_property = {
            response: resp,
            pathname: pathname,
            accumulator: "",
        };
        req.addListener( "data", data_listener );
        req.addListener( "end", end_listener );
    }
}).listen(8888);
```

Since `this` in the listener functions is the `request` object, I've borrowed the `request` object to accumulate the post data so that I can create my functions once and reuse them.

Is this an acceptable/safe approach?

Comment: Just `delete req.some_unique_property` at the bottom of the `end_listener` function

Comment: @Raynos: That would seem like a good idea, though I assume the request object gets destroyed once the response is closed. Still, I'll delete either way.

Comment: It does get destroyed, just as soon as response is destroyed. There's no persisting after an element is removed, that I've ever seen. Now, a reference can persist, and deleting a reference, doesn't delete the item. But that's pointer semantics.

Comment: @patrick_dw You can also use `.bind` if the callback functions do not give `this` some useful object. If you prefer to not alter the `req` you can just `.bind` some data into your callbacks including the req. This is more computationally expensive though

Comment: @Raynos: Yes, since the `.bind()` would need to take place in each request that occurs, I'd probably just use the anonymous functions before I did that.

Comment: Thanks for the random bounties. Not sure why I deserved them, but much appreciated.

Comment: @jcolebrandφ: Just spreading the wealth a bit. *Ugh, that made me a little sick.* Actually, giving you two instead of one was a little bit of an accident. Your lucky day I guess!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the latter approach versus many anonymous functions, because it makes it easier to organize code. Should the code to handle data grow large, the former has the potential to be a giant function with anonymous functions inside, and much harder to maintain.

With the latter, I can easily break code out into separate modules to keep things organized. It also lets me document the individual handlers easily if I use something like JSDoc for documentation.

The only recommendation I can give with the latter is some comment indicating what `this` is meant to represent so someone else that reads the code over doesn't have to spend too much time thinking on it.

Comment: Good idea about commenting. Perhaps I'd make a variable reference. But do you know if there are any potentially negative effects to doing this?

Comment: @patrick_dw I would say the main negative effect would be with smaller projects, where in my opinion having all related functionality in one place is easier to work with than breaking it out. `createServer` has everything you need to know about the server's functionality all one place, so you don't need to run around to other files / parts of the file to see where the handler function might be.

Comment: @patrick_dw However, as the size of the project increases, one giant `createServer` with all the handlers listed inside becomes more overwhelming than it's worth, and it's better to break out the different pieces of functionality.

Comment: @patrick_dw regarding your stance on the `req` object, I wouldn't consider that abuse personally. Being able to easily expand objects to fit your needs is a strength in my opinion.

Comment: Alright, good to know. I wasn't sure if those internally generated objects were sacred. Felt a little iffy adding a property to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is *probably* nothing wrong with it, but does it sound like a good idea?

Anonymous functions are cheap. Any current JS engine can create millions of them per second, that's a few orders of magnitude more than achievable request rates.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and you're right, reconstructing the functions isn't a big deal. I just prefer to avoid it if possible. *Does it sound like a good idea?* In terms of effectiveness, yes. In terms of that nagging feeling that I'm using the request object outside of its intended purpose, no. So I'm a little torn on this one. Definitely not a huge deal though.

Comment: Since anonymous functions are cheap, I was vouching for not abusing the request object, using closures as your 1st example instead :)

Answer (score 1):

A) I don't see a reason to *not* use functions like that, I think it makes things cleaner, there's already going to be another layer to the callstack, whether it's anonymous or done like this, so make the code programmer readable.

B) how is this not what a routing layer is used for? I don't see the distinction. Granted, I prefer to invert my req-method and my path, but they effectively work the same.

Comment: Yes, this is for a routing layer. No distinction. And I agree about the functions, but the question was more about the appropriateness of abusing the `request` object.

Comment: Abuse it all you like. That's perfectly viable.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like premature optimization to me. The way I usually handle this kind of stuff goes along the lines of:

```
require('http').createServer(function( req, res ) {
  if( req.method === "POST" ) {
    var buf = [];
    req.on('data', [].push.bind(buf)).on('end', function(){
      // do my thing with buf
    });
  }
}).listen(8888);
```

And by the way, in your second example, you should factor out the `require('url')`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really worried about performance, you could edit the [http library itself](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/http.js) to fir your need to custom inherited request objects as needed.

Apparently the http library already gives you a door to redefine your request class, and it should look like something like this:

```
function MyNewRequest( options, cb ){
    http.ClientRequest.call(self, options, cb); //Call the original constructor

    this.on('data', this.customData ); //Hook the event, and now we are the object
}
util.inherits(MyNewRequest, http.ClientRequest); //Inherit the original object

MyNewRequest.prototype.customData = function(data){

}

var oldRequest = http.request;
http.request = function( options, cb ){ //Override the original ClientRequest provider
    if( options.path == "/upload" ) //If it is our special path, return our new object 
        return new MyNewRequest( options, cb );

    return oldRequest( options, cb );
}
```